# What did Jesus mean in Matthew 16:18?

Tags: peter, matthew

When Jesus proclaimed that Peter was his Rock in Matthew 16:18-19, did he mean that Peter was given divine authority to change God's commandments and or statutes here on earth?

Comment: Please [edit] this to quote from the translation you are using.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For your question to work here, you would need to specify the group or denomination of Christians whose answer you are interested in. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) As it is now, your question could have as many different answers as there are Christian denominations—and questions here must be objectively answerable rather than being discussion-starters.

Comment: Calling Peter a rock does not mean that Peter was being given divine authority over anything. Calling Peter rock was not a prophecy about a  new covenant. The name change itself did not change things at that time.

Comment: I very much doubt that there is any denomination which claims Peter was given authority to change God's commandments -- even the RCC (see CCC 880 foll.)

Comment: The specificity of Matthew 18:19 in contrast and comparison to 16:18, might make for a better question regarding church organization and authority.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What Jesus was referring here was the legacy of the Torah from father to son. That's why he use the word "rock" (eben, in hebrew, is formed from the conjunction of the words father and son). He was putting Peter on a special place, and tell him that he has to be a leader based on the "old school" of the Torah, meaning that he has the responsibility of transferred the Jesus's interpretation of the Torah to the future members of the "first church".
Of course the "new covenant" didn't change the commandments of the Torah and no one, not even Jesus as the Messiah, has the authority or the will to change anything(Mat 5:18). What happens on that council is a huge misinterpretation.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer. Can you tell us what group of Christians it represents, and provide a link or to two materials from that group supporting your answer? See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) Meanwhile, I do hope you'll stick around, and browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score -3):

**What did Jesus mean in Matthew 16:18?**

> Matthew 16:15-18  He saith unto them, But whom say ye that I am?   And
>   Simon Peter answered and said, Thou art the Christ, the Son of the
>   living God.   And Jesus answered and said unto him, Blessed art thou,
>   Simon Barjona: for flesh and blood hath not revealed it unto thee, but
>   my Father which is in heaven.   And I say also unto thee, That thou
>   art Peter, and upon this rock I will build my church; and the gates of
>   hell shall not prevail against it

Some argue that Jesus was describing the statement that Peter had just made, that Jesus is "the Christ, the Son of the living God" as being the “rock” of faith that would be the foundation of the church.

Comment: This answer would be improved by stating the case.